# Angular JS XML data display issue

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, xml, rss

I'm trying to learn Xml and AngularJs, and I have some issues. I am not able to display the img tag of my feed, well i suppose it's enclosure tag but it does'nt work. 
For the title or description there's no problems

Anyone knows how I can fix it ?

Thanks a lot and here goes my code!

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in feed.entries | filter:searchText">
  <td>
    <img ng-src="{{item.enclosure}}" />
  </td>
  <td>
    <a href="#/feed/{{feed.id}}/item/{{item.title|hash}}">
      <strong ng-bind-html="item.title"></strong>
    </a>
    <br/>
    <span ng-bind-html="item.contentSnippet"></span>
  </td>
  <td>
    {{item.publishedDate | rssDate}}
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: How are you translating your XML to JSON?

Answer (score 0):

You have to take the attribute `url` of your `enclosure` tag. Try:

```
<img ng-src="{{item.enclosure._url}}" />
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, but it still doesn't work. When I inspect the img element the ng-src attribute is empty...

Comment: Can you post a sample of an item from feed?

Comment: <item><description>L'AssemblÃ©e gÃ©nÃ©rale de la Ligue, fin fÃ©vrier, s'annonce dÃ©licate pour son prÃ©sident, FrÃ©dÃ©ric Thiriez :  l'UCPF, l'un des deux syndicats de clubs, estime qu'il Â«a failli Ã  sa missionÂ» et appelle Ã  sa dÃ©mission.</description><pubDate>Thu, 17  Dec 2015 14:24:00 +0100</pubDate><enclosure url="http://medias.lequipe.fr/img-photo-jpg/lfp-l-ucpf-le-syndicat-des-clubs-de-l2-demande-la-da-mission-de-fra-da-ric-thiriez/1500000000624930/0-600-0-70/2983b.jpg" length="50000" type="image/jpeg"/></item>

Comment: I modified the original answer. Check that. Are you using xml2json library to parse xml to json?

Answer (score 0):

```
<item><title>Foot - LFP - LFP : l'UCPF demande la dÃ©mission de FrÃ©dÃ©ric Thiriez</title><link>http://www.lequipe.fr/Football/Actualites/Lfp-l-ucpf-le-syndicat-des-clubs-de-l2-demande-la-demission-de-frederic-thiriez/617436#xtor=RSS-1</link><description>L'AssemblÃ©e gÃ©nÃ©rale de la Ligue, fin fÃ©vrier, s'annonce dÃ©licate pour son prÃ©sident, FrÃ©dÃ©ric Thiriez :  l'UCPF, l'un des deux syndicats de clubs, estime qu'il Â«a failli Ã  sa missionÂ» et appelle Ã  sa dÃ©mission.</description><pubDate>Thu, 17  Dec 2015 14:24:00 +0100</pubDate><enclosure url="http://medias.lequipe.fr/img-photo-jpg/lfp-l-ucpf-le-syndicat-des-clubs-de-l2-demande-la-da-mission-de-fra-da-ric-thiriez/1500000000624930/0-600-0-70/2983b.jpg" length="50000" type="image/jpeg"/></item>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you want to use Image SRC Tag or a Link HREF Tag. I can only see HREF Tag on your Script.

For HREF use this:

```
<a ng-href="#/feed/{{feed.id}}/item/{{item.title|hash}}"></a>
```

For SRC use this:

```
<img ng-src="{{SOMETHING.LIKETHIS}}">
```

Best of Luck.